# How to ingore variable with no integar

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I am scraping some data off a site 
the variable "scraped" can have a int or just be a str 
ie. "1 Block" or "No Blocks"

When there is a int I extract it and execute some code

```
value = re.findall(r'\d+', scrapped)
new_value = int(value[0])
...
```

however when scraped is just a string with no number my program breaks
with error

> IndexError: list index out of range

how can I go about either ignoring it when its just a str 
 or check first if there is a int and continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might harness `re.search` for that task following way:

```
if re.search(r'\d+', scrapped):
    value = re.findall(r'\d+', scrapped)
    new_value = int(value[0])
    ...
```

Keep in mind pattern should be same in `re.search` and `re.findall`.

Comment: I over complicated it in my head, I feel silly now 
I just put it in a if statement and its working